# Best Tools for Developing with JavScript, CSOM and SPServices

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I think this is worth kicking off a discussion on here.

I currently use SharePoint Designer 2010 + FireFox + firebug and it is a bit heavy going for me to write (as editor is basic) but very quick to test ( using alerts or debugDiv.innerHtml = ‘what ever’). Now this was ok for a few functions but wI am starting to write losts of nested closures in ever more functions and object definitions. Hence, I could do with better tool support.  Also, I tend to develop my JS in Style Library/scipt (content db)  so that I can check in periodically. I wonder also if I really should have the js locally ( add file:// to master page)  until the final checkin then this would allow me to use editors like Aptana or the JavaScript Parser addon for Vs2010 or Resharper.

Comment: I've converted this question to a Wiki because this is more of a poll rather than a question that can be definitively answered.

Answer (score 1):

I use VS 2012 and Chrome. I think it's the best one combo you can have to work with JavaScript, CSOM and SPServices

Comment: I think that is something I should adopt. Out of interest are you storing your js file on the file system both in dev and in prod.  I really want to interact with the content db as in  /Style Library/Scripts as I am a big fan of version control.

Comment: Doh! I just had one of those ( omg I am a dumbass) moments! ... Got talking to one of the excellent Oracle devs who works for my client just now, and bemoaned the issues I have raised here. I suggested I didn't think there way to have an external editor with SPD ..then I realised there probably is! I have now configured and reopened my big library in vs2012 doh!